# javascript variable showing unexpected result

Tags: javascript, scope

Why I'm getting a ReferenceError: can't find variable `lang1` in the console?
If `lang` exists shouldn't lang1 exist too?...

```
<body>
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" placeholder="Datetimerpicker">
        <input id="lang" type="text" placeholder="language" value="en"><div class="select">select language</div>

    <script>
     $(".select").click(function(){
        var lang = $('#lang').val();
        var lang1 = lang;
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

And shouldn't `lang = "en"`? I'm getting `lang = <input id=​"lang" type=​"text" placeholder=​"language" value="en">​` in the console

Comment: conflict of variable name and id.

Comment: @epascarello I was thinking that, but `lang` the variable is local to the function. *edit* oh wait now I see what you mean, yes that's it.

Comment: That is the issue, OP is treating lang1 as a global when it is a local.

Comment: well, where are you using `lang`? since you're own ASSIGNING to it in the above code, there's no way to produce that error, since it's produced by trying to READ from an undefined variable.

Comment: @MarcB I (we) think he's typing those symbols into the developer console.

Comment: YEs, I'm using the developer console to run these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the browser debugging tools for your function, you have to do things the way the tools intend.  Just typing `lang` and `lang1` into the console command prompt won't really do what you want. In this case, the symbol `lang` will refer to the global symbol created by implication from your use of `lang` as the "id" of the `<input>` field.

You can use the tools to set a breakpoint in your event handler. One easy way is to add a `debugger` statement to the start of the "click" handler:

```
 $(".select").click(function(){
    debugger;
    var lang = $('#lang').val();
    var lang1 = lang;
});
```

From that point, the debugging tools will provide a way for you to look at the values of variables in the active function (and the functions that got you there).

Comment: Understood the first part of it (debugger issue) but unfortunately my knowledge doesn't allow me to understand how to debug it (i don't understand what "debugger" does. Thank you!

Comment: @PauloJaneiro the `debugger` statement causes the browser to pause execution. In the developer console, it'll show you where the code is paused, and provide a way to look at variables etc. Different browsers provide different tools, though they're generally similar. [Here is an introduction for the tools in Google Chrome.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#debugging-javascript) Without those tools, it's like working in a dark room!

Answer (score 3):

You can not reference the `lang` and `lang1` in the console since they are local to the click's closure. The reason why `lang` is defined in the console is it will use any element id that matches your variable. Change the variable to langX and you will have the same error.

Comment: Got it (half of it, truly). I changed the ID to LangX and now both lang and lang1 return undefined as I expected (after your suggestion!)